# cann't make model when build linux kernel

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

i am trying to build linux kernel(6.3.11) on ubuntu 23.04 (linux kernel version is 6.2.0.24-generic).
i did the following steps:

1. cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
2. make menuconfig (i didn't select anything, just save and exit)
3. make -j32

at the step 3, i got errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2GjT.png)
and the makefile:2025 is

```
KBUILD_MODULES := 1
```

gcc and g++ version is 12.2.0

i search this line `KBUILD_MODULES := 1` but i don't know how to fix it.

i got it right when build the same linux kernel version with the build system

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't [paste code or errors as pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).  Instead just paste the errors you got.  You could put the error messages through some automatic translator.  Then you will get more answers.

Comment: Did you try without step 2?  If you copied a config from somewhere to `.config`, there's no need to run `menuconfig` (unless you intend on changing some configuration symbols).

Comment: line 2025 in the 6.3.11 kernel Makefile is a few lines later in the build-dirs recursive make.  That makes (sic) more sense as it looks like that make is failing and returning error code 2. One problem with -j32 is that your error message may get split many lines apart, so you are missing earlier messages.